# Javascript: Open Two Pdf Adobe Side By Side in Same Window

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf, adobe

Is there a way in Javascript or Angular to view Two Adobe PDFs side by side in the same window? I see a lot of resources manually

Trying to do it in code, maybe with window.open or some other syntax

https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/how-do-i-display-two-pdf-documents-side-by-side/td-p/7825917

https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-view-pdf-separate-pdf-side-side-q144843.aspx

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0qRM5koats

[image]

Utilizing Angular 10 Typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would open them in multiple iframes.

```
<iframe src="path/to/pdf1.pdf"></iframe>
<iframe src="path/to/pdf2.pdf"></iframe>
```

Using window.open

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write(`<iframe width="${width}" height="${height}" src="path/to/pdf1.pdf" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><iframe width="${width}" height="${height}" src="path/to/pdf2.pdf" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`)
```

Comment: is there alternative besides iframe, if getting this error? "display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'"